# WSO2 - Identity Server 6.1.0 Configuring Internal Crypto Provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can we configure Internal Crypto Provider ?
I tried to uncomment the following under the deployment.toml using info put under carbon.xml but it is not working.

```
[keystore.internal]
file_name = "repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
type = "JKS"
password = "wso2carbon"
alias = "wso2carbon"
key_password = "wso2carbon"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the file name by simply: wso2carbon.jks